# Error while trying to fetch data from Internet without Wifi connection using RxJava and Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

Hello guys I have in my BaseActivity the following function.

```
override fun <T> subscribeToInternet(observable: Observable<Response<BaseResponse<T>>>, observer: Observer<BaseResponse<T>>) {
    observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe { observer.onSubscribe(it) }
            .doOnError {
                Log.d(TAG, it.message)
                observer.onError(it)
            }
            .doOnComplete { observer.onComplete() }
            .doOnNext {
                Log.d(TAG, "${it.body() ?: "no body"}")
                Log.d(TAG, "${it.errorBody()?.string() ?: "no error body"}")
                Log.d(TAG, it.code().toString())
                when {
                    it.code() == 401 -> {
                        view.userUnauthenticated()
                        observer.onNext(BaseResponse(false, "unauthenticated", null))
                        Log.d(TAG, "UNAUTHENTICATED")
                    }
                    it.code() == 423 -> {
                        view.userBlocked()
                        observer.onNext(BaseResponse(false, "blocked", null))
                        Log.d(TAG, "BLOCKED")
                    }
                    it.isSuccessful -> observer.onNext(it.body()!!)
                    it.code() == 429 -> observer.onNext(BaseResponse(false, "Too many attempts", null))
                    it.code() == 400 -> observer.onNext(BaseResponse(false, "Invalid Email or password", null))
                    else -> observer.onNext(BaseResponse(false, "", null))
                }
            }
            .subscribe()
}
```

And I handle the error in the observer's onNext() if the server returns a response, but the problem when there's no Internet connection on the device at all!! It throws the following exception

```
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableDoOnEach$DoOnEachObserver.onError(ObservableDoOnEach.java:119)
    at io.reactivex.internal.observers.DisposableLambdaObserver.onError(DisposableLambdaObserver.java:64)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.checkTerminated(ObservableObserveOn.java:276)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:172)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
```

And this is the usage of the previously mentioned function

```
override fun sendLoginRequest(email: String, password: String, fcm_token: String) {
    subscribeToInternet(dataManager.sendLoginRequest(email, password, fcm_token), this)
}

override fun onComplete() {

}

override fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
    DisposableManager.add(d)
}

override fun onNext(t: BaseResponse<LoginData>) {
    if(t.status) {
        Log.d(TAG, "${t.data}")
        dataManager.createLoginSession(t.data!!)
        view.loginSuccess()
    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, t.message)
        view.showError(t.message)
    }
}

override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
    view.showToastError()
    Log.d(TAG, e.message)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That problem is connected with the way you subscribing to observable. According to
 documentation when using `subscribe()` without passing action for handling errors, you should receive [`OnErrorNotImplementedException`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/exceptions/OnErrorNotImplementedException.html) when source throws exceptions - that's because default exception handler from RxJavaPlugins is used.

To resolve that problem use one of overloaded `subscribe` methods with `onError` parameter. For example, [public final Disposable subscribe(Consumer onNext,
        Consumer onError)](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-io.reactivex.functions.Consumer-)

Comment: Thanks for your precise response.. But isn't doOnError enough for error handling?

Comment: @TahaMalas, no, it's not enough. `doOnError` only allow to trigger additional action when error happened. According to observable contract, when error happened your source will be terminated. So when you call `subscribe`  with `onError` parameter, you are sure that properly handle termination of your source (in case of throwing exception).

Comment: Thank you so much it worked like a charm.. So should I move doOnNext, doOnError, doOnComplete and doOnSubscribe and pass them in the subscribe parameters?

Comment: I recommend you pass you observer directly in `subscribe()` and return `Subscription` back from your method, because in some cases you should manually trigger Subscription.unsubbscribe() to free up occupied resources. And by the way, you can extract you switch/case block in `map` operator. In my opinion, it will be more Rx idiomatic.